# Terraform MySQL provider 'Error: Failed to install providers'

Tags: mysql, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I run into this error when I begin my 'terraform init' sequence.
Not sure how to resolve it.

Things I tried: 
terraform 0.13upgrade . 
tried changing out pinned version of mysql  
search documentation but couldn't find similar issues.

error output after running 'terraform init'

```
- Finding hashicorp/mysql versions matching ">= 1.5.*"...

Error: Failed to install providers

Could not find required providers, but found possible alternatives:

  hashicorp/mysql -> terraform-providers/mysql

If these suggestions look correct, upgrade your configuration with the
following commands:
    terraform 0.13upgrade .
    terraform 0.13upgrade ..\mysql-module-test\mysql_server
```

main.tf

```
provider "mysql" {
  alias = "create_users"

  endpoint = format("%s:3306", module.mysql_server.primary_fqdn)
  username = var.administrator_login
  password = var.administrator_password
}
```

versions.tf

```
# Configure terraform and azure provider
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = ">= 2.25.0"
    random  = ">= 2.2.0"
    mysql   = ">= 1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running the two commands listed in the error message? If that didn't work, it'd be helpful to edit your question to include what happened.

Comment: Is this issue fixed?

Comment: @NancyXiong
It actually kept throwing the same error, to meet my deadline I just removed the 'mysql' provider. but I do appreciate you taking the time to provide feedback becuase I was unaware we could format the provider like this:   source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the hint, try to run `terraform 0.13upgrade` to upgrade your configuration. The version control should look like this,

```
# Configure terraform and azure provider
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13.0"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.25.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = ">= 2.2.0"
    }
    mysql = {
      source  = "terraform-providers/mysql"
      version = ">= 1.5"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have a github?

Comment: Sorry. I have not a github account.

Comment: Anyone know why this is still requiring the `features {}` block? This is blocking my module right now.